# Checks and Complete missing data in a SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to check and then fill in the missing data from the results of a view?

I am trying to check if there is any missing data in a 30 minutes time slot. There are multiple rows of data with different DeviceID for the same 30-minute timeslot.

Sample view :

```
DeviceID   Occupancy  Time
   A        1         10:30
   B        1         10:30
   C        0         10:30
   D        1         10:30
   A        0         11:00
   D        1         11:00
```

As you can see there are 2 rows missing from the 11:00 timeslot which are DeviceID = B and C.
Below is what I want a query to insert to the view based on [ DeviceID = B and C are missing].

```
DeviceID   Occupancy  Time
   B                  11:00
   C                  11:00
```

So this is what the View will look like after the missing data are filled

Desired Result:

```
DeviceID   Occupancy  Time
   A        1         10:30
   B        1         10:30
   C        0         10:30
   D        1         10:30
   A        0         11:00
   B       NULL       11:00
   C       NULL       11:00
   D        1         11:00
```

I did not try anything yet as I have no clue on how and what to do.

Another Question:

What if  i have a table like this :

```
DeviceID   Occupancy  Time    RoomID  
   A        1         10:30    01-01
   B        1         10:30    01-02
   C        0         10:30    01-03
   D        1         10:30    01-04
   A        0         11:00    01-01
   D        1         11:00    01-04
```

Then, what changes should i make to the given answer?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the data:

```
select d.deviceid, ti.time, t.occupancy
from (select distinct deviceid from t) d cross join
     (select distinct time from t) ti left join
     t
     on t.deviceid = d.deviceid and t.time = ti.time
order by ti.time, d.deviceid;
```

Note:  You don't really *insert* into "views".  You can insert into table.  The above query is a way to formulate the view so it has all the rows you want.

Comment: Had just created a fiddle for this exact query prior to answering here it is http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c29c2/3

Comment: Thanks, guys. Anyways is it possible for me to implement the above query in a create view query?

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi no worries.

Comment: @Nick is there a way to check fore the missing rows? before filling in with the data? Just to make sure that after executing, the query fills up the right ones.

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi the query is guaranteed by design to fill the right ones. But you can check for the missing ones with `SELECT * FROM occupancy WHERE [Occupancy] IS NULL`

Comment: @Nick ```SELECT * FROM occupancy WHERE [Occupancy] IS NULL```  only shows results after i fill in the missing rows. But what if i want to check if there is any missing row before i fill in? Is it possible? Thank you once again for your help!

Comment: @JamesFrancoHadi sorry I don't understand. Ask another question and you can explain in more detail.